# program for apache mahout classification using java

Tags: apache, mahout

I need a program for classification of data using `apache mahout` in java.
The program mentioned in `Mahout in Action` uses Hadoop.
But i need the program with pure java `not` using Hadoop.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain me to do with java and Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question on the Mahout mailing list:

user@mahout.apache.org

See http://mahout.apache.org/